# rails migration error default value wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an migration error in rails.

```
  def self.up
    change_column_default :course_objects, :active, :default => "0"
  end
```

error is

```
Mysql2::Error: Invalid default value for 'active': ALTER TABLE `course_objects`  CHANGE `active` `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '---\n:default: \'0\'\n'
```

also tried this:

```
  def self.up
    change_column_default :course_objects, :active, :default => 0
  end
```

same error

What is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change_column_default` [takes the `default` as the third parameter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default), not a hash including a `:default` key. You want:

```
change_column_default :course_objects, :active, 0
```